# Extracting ip address from mysql query list using python

Tags: python, mysql, list, ip, ip-address

I would like to extract an ip address from mysql using python.

here is my code,

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=mysql_localhost, user=user, password=password, database=database)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("select inet_ntoa(server) as ip from settings" )
#print 'Data inserted into Database'
results = cursor.fetchone()
print(results)
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

and my result is

```
('192.168.0.15',)
```

how can i save the result above to an ip address?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean with "how can i save the result above to an ip address?". It's unclear what you actually want to do.

Comment: do you mean having the 192.168.0.15 value instead of ('192.168.0.15',)?

Comment: Yes, and also be able to use this value to connect to a server

Comment: I would like to save this ip address to a variable called mysql_localhost  and connect to a database using cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=mysql_localhost, user=user, password=password, database=database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing

```
results = cursor.fetchone()
```

`results` has the value `('192.168.0.15',)`. That is a tuple consisting of one element, a string.

You get it with `results[0]`.

If you want to connect to that host, simply do

```
mysql_target_host = results[0]
```

and then

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=mysql_target_host, user=user, password=password, database=database)
```

as I strictly vote against `mysql_localhost` because that could lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

That is a human readable interpretation of an IP address?

You could use [IPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IPy/) to parse it further.

Im not sure what else you are after